# Get Modern Browsers to Recognize Ajax/JQuery Login and Ask to Save Password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am using jQuery (latest) and have a entirely ajax through post login form. The form is monitored by this code:

```
    $("form").live("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var input = {};
    input.url = $(this).attr('action');
    input.data = $(this).serializeArray();

    var output = Site.getResponse(input);

    if(output.success) {
        params = {};
        params.title = 'Dashboard';
        params.url = '/user/dashboard';

        Page.instance().load(params);
    }
});
```

So, essentially the browser should still recognize the post because it happens from the form's submit, I just use jQuery to stop that submit so I can process it. Is there a way to "trick" modern browsers into saving the password for my site without iframes, please.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. You are intercepting and stopping the post, but still want the browser to treat it as a post.

Comment: What @Oded said. Also, the browser should *not* still recognize the post. You're stopping it.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO the best way to handle login is to add this line to the end of the login script

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

or some constant url, depending on what you want. This way the page doesn't change and the form submits, therefore the browser remember's the password.